# How to make a movable control in c#?

Tags: c#

How to make a movable control in c#?

Two circles with a line joining b/w them.

if we move one circle in any direction the other circle remains fixed but the line changes its position according to the first circle.

i want the idea .....pls help me if u have?

Comment: Maybe it's only me, but I really didn't understand your question. We're talking about WinForms, right? Now, can you explain what exactly is the part that you're struggling with?

Comment: actually i have edges and nodes............i represent nodes with circle and edges with lines....as in control flow graph....so now i want that i can move the circles in output to make the view better of control flow graph. Actually i am representing a CFG from Adjacency matrix...

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling us if this is a Winform application, WPF or Silverlight.

To me it sounds like WPF could be the right technology for this.
You could use the shape objects to draw circles and lines.
[Link to MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx#paths)

Comment: Are you using the `System.Drawing` namespace?

Comment: You probably need to do a fair bit of coding then overriding `OnMouseDown`, `OnMouseUp`, `OnMouseMove`etc.